# Windows Store Apps 8.1 and VisualStateManager

Tags: visual-studio, windows-8.1

I am having a difficult time solving a Visual State problem after moving to VS2013 and Windows Store Apps for 8.1.  I have an app with a AppBar "About" button that takes the user to the About page.  Works just fine.  I want a stackpanel on the About page to change orientation when the view changes to Portrait.  Been working on this for hours and reading countless websites with exact replicas of this code, but mine will not work.  Any ideas?

Here's the C# code on AboutPage.cs:

```cs
private void AboutPage_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewSize.Height / e.NewSize.Width >= 1)
        {
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Portrait", true);
        }
        else
        {
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "DefaultLayout", true);
        }
    }
```

Here's the XAML on AboutPage.xaml:

```xaml
<Page
x:Name="pageRoot"
x:Class="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.AboutPage"
DataContext="{Binding DefaultViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
xmlns:common="using:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.Common"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d" SizeChanged="AboutPage_SizeChanged">

<Page.Resources>
    <!-- TODO: Delete this line if the key AppName is declared in App.xaml -->
    <!--<x:String x:Key="AppName">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</x:String>-->
</Page.Resources>

<!--
    This grid acts as a root panel for the page that defines two rows:
    * Row 0 contains the back button and page title
    * Row 1 contains the rest of the page layout
-->
<Grid x:Name="pageMainGrid" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
        <TransitionCollection>
            <EntranceThemeTransition/>
        </TransitionCollection>
    </Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="140"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!-- Back button and page title -->
    <Grid x:Name="pageHeaderGrid">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <StackPanel
            x:Name="headerStackPanel"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
            Background="#FF4617B4"
            Orientation="Horizontal" >
            <Button 
                x:Name="backButton" 
                Margin="39,59,39,0" 
                Command="{Binding NavigationHelper.GoBackCommand, ElementName=pageRoot}"
                Style="{StaticResource NavigationBackButtonNormalStyle}"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                AutomationProperties.Name="Back"
                AutomationProperties.AutomationId="BackButton"
                AutomationProperties.ItemType="Navigation Button"/>
            <TextBlock 
                x:Name="pageTitle" 
                Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}" 
                Grid.Column="1" 
                IsHitTestVisible="false" 
                TextWrapping="NoWrap" 
                VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
                Margin="0,0,30,40" 
                Text="{StaticResource AppName}"/>
        </StackPanel>            
    </Grid>

    <Grid
        x:Name="pageContentGrid"
        Grid.Row="1"
        Visibility="Visible">

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="20*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="142*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="150*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="372*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="150*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock 
            Grid.Column="1"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
            Margin="0,0,0,0" 
            TextAlignment="Center"
            Text="About"  
            FontSize="48" 
            FontFamily="Segoe UI"/>

        <ScrollViewer
            BorderThickness="0,2,0,0"
            BorderBrush="DarkGray"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="1"
            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
            Margin="0">

            <StackPanel
                Margin="40">

                <TextBlock
                    Text="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
                    FontSize="34" />

                <TextBlock
                    Text="by xxxxxxxxxx"
                    FontSize="24"/>

                <StackPanel
                    Orientation="Vertical"
                    Margin="0,25,0,0">

                    <TextBlock
                        Margin="0,6,0,0"
                        Padding="0,0,0,0"
                        Text="Website:"
                        FontSize="24"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

                    <HyperlinkButton
                        Margin="0,0,0,0"
                        Padding="-5,0,0,0"
                        FontSize="20"
                        NavigateUri="http://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        Content="www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com" />

                </StackPanel>

                <StackPanel
                    x:Name="emailStack"
                    Orientation="Vertical"
                    Margin="0,25,0,0">

                    <TextBlock
                        Margin="0,4,0,0"
                        Padding="0,0,0,0"
                        Text="Support Email:"
                        FontSize="24"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

                    <HyperlinkButton
                        Margin="0,0,0,0"
                        Padding="-5,0,0,0"
                        FontSize="20"
                        NavigateUri="mailto:xxxxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        Content="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com" />

                </StackPanel>

                <TextBlock
                    Margin="0,30,0,0"
                    Text="Feedback:"
                    FontSize="24"/>

                <TextBlock
                    TextWrapping="Wrap"
                    Margin="0,10,0,10"
                    FontSize="20" >

                    Please take a few moments to rate and review my application. 
                    Every little bit of encouragement and/or constructive feedback 
                    is appreciated.
                    <LineBreak /><LineBreak />
                    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

                </TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>

        <Rectangle
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Grid.RowSpan="2"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
            Fill="DarkGray" />

        <Rectangle
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="2"
            Grid.RowSpan="2"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
            Fill="DarkGray" />          
    </Grid>

  <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
      <VisualStateGroup>
          <VisualState x:Name="DefaultLayout">
              <Storyboard>
              </Storyboard>
           </VisualState>

           <VisualState x:Name="Portrait">
               <Storyboard>
                   <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="(StackPanel.Orientation)" 
                       Storyboard.TargetName="emailStack">
                       <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <Orientation>Horizontal</Orientation>
                             </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                       </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                   </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups> 

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 3):

This needs to be highlighted because it's the answer:

> Ok, finally... problem solved! The trick was to locate the VisualStateManager XAML block right after the Grid that contains the control you want to modify when changing screen size. I modified the AboutPage XALM block in my original post to show the correct configuration

This is a breaking change from .NET 4.5.1 where you can place the VisualStateManager before the controls that are effected.

Answer (score 1):

Putting the `VisualStateManager` within the main control in the content of your `Page` (usually a `Grid` or a `StackPanel`) should change the layout of your `AppBar`. Give it a try.

```xaml
<Page 
    ... 
    SizeChanged="Page_SizeChanged">

    <Page.BottomAppBar>
        <AppBar>
            <StackPanel
                x:Name="emailStack"
                Orientation="Vertical"
                Margin="0,25,0,0">

                <TextBlock
                    Margin="0,4,0,0"
                    Padding="0,0,0,0"
                    Text="Support Email:"
                    FontSize="24"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

                <HyperlinkButton
                    Margin="0,0,0,0"
                    Padding="-5,0,0,0"
                    FontSize="20"
                    NavigateUri="mailto:xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Content="xxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com" />
            </StackPanel>
        </AppBar>
    </Page.BottomAppBar>

    <Grid>
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup>
                <VisualState x:Name="DefaultLayout">
                    <Storyboard>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>

                <VisualState x:Name="Portrait">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(StackPanel.Orientation)" 
                            Storyboard.TargetName="emailStack">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    <Orientation>Horizontal</Orientation>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: I edited my original post with the changed code you suggested.  Thanks a lot for trying to assist, but your suggestion did not do the trick.

Comment: I forgot the `StackPanel` was inside an `AppBar`. I updated my answer.

Comment: Actually, my StackPanel isn't inside an AppBar.  I've updated my original post above to show the entire contents of the AboutPage.xaml file so you can see the entire arrangement.  Changing the orientation of this StackPanel is just a test to see if I can get this to work.  There's actually something more involved I want to do, but I just want to get VisualStateManager to work properly first.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ok, finally... problem solved!  The trick was to locate the VisualStateManager XAML block right after the Grid that contains the control you want to modify when changing screen size.  I modified the AboutPage XALM block in my original post to show the correct configuration.