# VisualStateManager in XAML won't update with new State

Tags: .net, vb.net, xaml, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I'm trying to add some screen size breakpoints to a Xaml/VB app in Windows 8.1.  I'm handling the SizeChanged event in the codebehind for my main view, and calling `VisualStateManager.GoToState` which should propagate to the predefined Visual States that are sitting in my .xaml file.  Here's the entire bit of code for a tiny example that should change the background color on a small screen, but doesn't.

**MainView.xaml**:

```xaml
<Page x:Name="PageRoot"
    x:Class="WinStoreMvvmTemplate.MainView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Grid Background="Red" x:Name="ContentGrid"></Grid>

    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualState x:Name="SmallLayout">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                        Storyboard.TargetName="ContentGrid"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Blue"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
</Page>
```

**MainView.xaml.vb**:

```vb
Public NotInheritable Class MainView : Inherits Page

    Private Sub WindowSizeChanged(sender As Object, e As SizeChangedEventArgs) _
            Handles Me.SizeChanged
        If e.NewSize.Width < 340 Then
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(Me, "SmallLayout", True)
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

The event is definitely firing on the code end and the `GoToState` method is definitely being called.

Any idea why the xaml isn't picking up these changes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well this is silly, but it [looks like](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19735860/1366033) the `VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups` needs to be inside of the Page's child element, which in this case is `Grid`.  I'll accept any other answer that can explain why that is.

**MainView.xaml.vb**:

```xaml
<Page x:Name="PageRoot"
    x:Class="WinStoreMvvmTemplate.View.MainView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Grid Background="Red" x:Name="ContentGrid">

        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup>
                <VisualState x:Name="RegularLayout"/>
                <VisualState x:Name="SmallLayout">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                            Storyboard.TargetName="ContentGrid"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Blue"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: +1 Never found an answer to the "why" either but would like to know...other than that it's made to apply implicitly to an `Element` and not a view. A more detailed explanation would be awesome.

Comment: I might open another question, but I can get everything to work just fine when I run the app, but can't get the designer to change view states like it did in the 8.0 templates.  I wonder why.  The designer support was really fantastic for the LayoutAwarePage.